# after a maxim number - wrap all remaining li items into a ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I think it's a lot easier to understand what i am trying to achieve just by posting the code. But the idea is. i have about 8 li items, but after 3, i would like to create a new li item called "more" and the remaining 5 items should be moved into a new `ul` that will act as a submenu.
here's the html

```
<ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
    <li>item5</li>
</ul>
```

here's the javascript

```
$('.ow_main_menu').each(function(){
    var max = 3
    if ($(this).find('li').length > max) {
        $(this).find('li:gt('+max+')').hide().end().append('<li class="show_more">More</li>');

        $('.show_more').hover( function(){
            /* stuck */
        });

    };
});
```

Here's how it should be like

```
<ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li class="show_more">More
        <ul>
            <li>item4</li>
            <li>item5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The show more part i got it working, but i have no idea on how to wrap the rest of the items.

Comment: you mean "wrap" not "warp" right?

Comment: haha. yes, sorry for the confusion. i'm trying now to edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is the following (though it still feels a little too clunky):

```
// using 'on()' to delegate the click-event handling to a 'ul' element
// that exists in the DOM, that becomes an ancestor to the created
// elements:
$('ul').on('click', 'li.more', function(e){
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});

// select all 'li' elements, retain only the 3rd (JavaScript's indexing is
// zero-based:
$('li').eq(2)
// get all the subsequent siblings:
.nextAll()
// wrap them all together within the supplied HTML:
.wrapAll('<li class="more">Read more<ul></ul></li>')
// find the ancestor 'ul' (to the 'li' elements returned by 'wrapAll()'):
.closest('ul')
// hide that 'ul':
.hide();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RVtE6/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).
- [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time mate. I love the click capabilities there. it was actually exact what i was trying to do. cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it:

```
var max = 3;

$('ul').children('li:gt(' + (max - 1) + ')')     // find all LI after max
       .wrapAll('<ul>').parent()                 // wrap with UL and get it
       .wrap('<li class="show_more">More</li>'); // wrap UL with LI.show_more
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n57g3/1/